# How can I change the colour of an ionic item-divider when it is clicked from the default

Tags: css, angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a ng-click assigned to an ionic item-divider as follows:

```html
<div class="item item-divider"  ng-click="toggleShowingProfile()">
  PROFILE
</div>
```

When this gets clicked it goes grey momentarily. I would like a much more subtle effect. I want it to go slightly lighter in colour so am trying to change the opacity like this:

```css
.item-divider{
  background-color: #336688;
  color: white;
}
.item-divider:active{
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

My CSS code seems to make no difference. Is there a way to override the default behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## CSS Only

The easiest way to override it is to give it a custom class and use that as your CSS selector. Also, the `item` is getting the `activated` class added to it on click, so `:active` won't change anything. To override you need to do something like this:

HTML:

```
<div class="item item-divider custom-item-divider" ng-click="toggleShowingProfile()">
  PROFILE
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.custom-item-divider.item-divider {
  background-color: #336688;
  color: white;
}
.custom-item-divider.item.activated {
  background-color: #336688;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
```

Codepen demo: http://codepen.io/brandyshea/pen/epEedW

Note: you could also use `<ion-item>` instead of using a `<div>` with the `item` class.

## Sass

If you are using [Sass](http://ionicframework.com/docs/cli/sass.html), you can override the Sass variables directly:

```
$item-divider-bg
$item-divider-color

$item-default-active-bg        
$item-default-active-border
```

See these variables here: https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/scss/_variables.scss#L311
and here:
https://github.com/driftyco/ionic/blob/master/scss/_variables.scss#L372

You will want to override the variables in your own Sass file, not Ionic's Sass files directly.

Let me know if you have any questions!

Comment: Perfect works a charm! I guess I need to start using custom classes rather than trying too override existing classes. Very helpful answer thanks.

Comment: You can override existing classes too but it requires the use of `!important` in most cases, and that's frowned upon by some people. :) Glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<div class="item item-divider"  ng-click="toggleShowingProfile()">
  PROFILE
</div>
```